# Using Sections from Layout page - not getting displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have defined a Section in my `_Layout.cshtml` page.

```
@RenderSection("xx", false)
```

Thereafter, I am trying to display this section on `Create.cshtml`. The code is as follows:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section xx {
    @*Stuff comes here*@
    <h1>sdsdds</h1>
}
```

However, nothing gets displayed

Comment: Does `Create.cshtml` use `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: @haim770 I think yes. have updated my post, please have a look.

Comment: Did you make sure the section contents aren't hidden by some CSS rules? In other words, did you check the actual HTML returned from the server ("view-source")?

Comment: Yes. I did. It's not found in the websites view- source.

Comment: In _Layout.cshtml page where `@RenderSection("xx",false)` is define